# Смена фрагментов в android

Tags: android, fragment-transaction, fragment-manager

Помогите понять фрагменты. 
Я добавляю фрагмент в `FrameLayout`:

```
        FragmentTransaction fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        startDialog = new StartDialogFragment();
        fTrans.add(R.id.gameAreaFrag, startDialog);
        fTrans.commit();
```

Далее добавляю ещё фрагмент:

```
    FragmentTransaction fTrans2 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fTrans2.add(R.id.gameAreaFrag, areaFrag);
    fTrans2.commit();
```

Через некоторое время я хочу отобразить первый фрагмент - `startDialog`, не перезагружая его, второй мне больше не нужен:

```
        fTrans.remove(areaFrag);
        fTrans.commit();
```

В результате фрагмент находится в `FrameLayout`, но не отображается.

В чём дело? Методы `show()`, `hide()` также на ситуацию не влияют.

Comment: добавьте первую транзакцию в бекстек fTrans.addToBackStack()

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, вам необходимо просто заменять фрагменты, в таком случае следует использовать метод

```
fTrans.add(R.id.gameAreaFrag, startDialog);
```

только единожды, за время существования activity, далее необходимо использовать

```
fTrans.replace(R.id.gameAreaFrag, areaFrag);
```

В конце также не забудьте commit()